# Problem with updating the table via UPDATE SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using MS SQL Server. I have 2 tables:

`Table1` stores information about the individual object number (`Object_id`), the number of its property (`Prop_id`) and the value of this property (`Value`).

Example

| Object_id | Prop_id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 980 |
| 1 | 76 |  |
| 2 | 55 | 970 |
| 2 | 76 |  |
| 3 | 55 | 960 |
| 3 | 76 |  |

`Table 2` contains the values of the object properties:

| NUM | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 980 | ABC |
| 970 | DEF |
| 960 | HIJ |

I need to update table 1 with values from table 2. I need to put "Name" in the "Value" column for a property with index 76. The connection of the two tables should be by the fields "Value" for property 55 in Table 1 and "Num" in Table 2.

In the end, I want to get this:

| Object_id | Prop_id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 980 |
| 1 | 76 | ABC |
| 2 | 55 | 970 |
| 2 | 76 | DEF |
| 3 | 55 | 960 |
| 3 | 76 | HIJ |

Please help me write a query that will give the desired result!

I have already tried several SQL queries, but they either do not update the table at all, or substitute only the first value from the data sample.

My attempt:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Value = name1.name
FROM (SELECT Table2.name 
      FROM Table1 
      JOIN Table2 ON Table2.num = Table1.Value 
                  AND Table1.Prop_id = 55) AS name1
WHERE Table1.Prop_id = 76
```

This attempt updates the values in the table, but inserts only the first value from the `SELECT` query into all rows (i.e. the ABC value in all rows with property 76).

Comment: **Side note:** SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 have reached end of life several years ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier if you write the query step by step

First, you need to get the value from Table2 link to Table1

```
select *
from   Table1 t1
       inner join Table2 t2  on t1.Value = t2.NUM
```

| Object_id | Prop_id | Value | NUM | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 980 | 980 | ABC |
| 2 | 55 | 970 | 970 | DEF |
| 3 | 55 | 960 | 960 | HIJ |

You will get the `Object_id` with the associate `Name` value from `Table2`

Next, you join it back to `Table1` for update

```
select *
from   Table1 t1
       inner join Table2 t2  on t1.Value = t2.NUM
       inner join Table1 t1u on t1.Object_id = t1u.Object_id
where  t1u.Prop_id = 76
```

| Object_id | Prop_id | Value | NUM | Name | Object_id | Prop_id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 980 | 980 | ABC | 1 | 76 | *null* |
| 2 | 55 | 970 | 970 | DEF | 2 | 76 | *null* |
| 3 | 55 | 960 | 960 | HIJ | 3 | 76 | *null* |

Verify the result is what you want, just change the query to a `update` query

```
update t1u
set    Value = t2.Name
from   Table1 t1
       inner join Table2 t2  on t1.Value = t2.NUM
       inner join Table1 t1u on t1.Object_id = t1u.Object_id
where  t1u.Prop_id = 76
```

And you will get the result you want in `Table1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to understand what are you doing.

Based on the mapping between Value in Table1 and Num in Table2 for property 55, you may do this by using a common table expression (CTE) to update Table1 with the values from Table2 for property 76.

```
WITH PropertyNames AS 
(
    SELECT t1.Object_id, t2.Name
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Value = t2.NUM
    WHERE t1.Prop_id = 55 
) 
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.Value = pn.Name 
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN PropertyNames pn ON t1.Object_id = pn.Object_id 
WHERE t1.Prop_id = 76;
```

**Explanation**: when `Prop_id = 55`, the CTE `PropertyNames` is constructed to translate `Object_id` to the relevant property name (`Name`) from Table 2.

Then, we update Table 1 with the relevant property names (Name) obtained from the CTE where `Prop_id = 76`.

Using the mapping between property 55 and the appropriate names in Table2, this query will update the Value in Table1 for property 76.